# mariadb uninstall but not clean

Tags: linux, mariadb, amazon-linux

I created Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type operating system using ec2 of aws.

And create the file below

```
sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/maria.repo

[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

It was well installed and run well.

And I deleted the packages shown in the code below.

using `sudo yum remove -y`

`yum list installed mariadb\*`

Then I switched to centos7-amd64 and tried to reinstall it, and the disaster appeared.

```
sudo vim /etc/yum.repos.d/maria.repo

[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

error code

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-207 ~]$ sudo yum install MariaDB-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                            | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol >= 2.5-6.el7 for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-client for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-client-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-compat for package: MariaDB-common-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol >= 2.5-6.el7 for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-client-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-compat.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsepol >= 2.5-6.el7 for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsepol >= 2.5-6.el7
           Installed: libsepol-2.1.7-3.12.amzn1.x86_64 (installed)
               libsepol = 2.1.7-3.12.amzn1
Error: Package: MariaDB-client-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_209)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

There seems to be a conflict, but no package is found and not deleted.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-207 ~]$ sudo yum list installed mariadb\*
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

"2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections" this a problem?
How can I look up and delete?

What should I do?

What is the cause?

If my information is not enough, please let me know what you lack.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should created Amazon Linux 2 AMI instead and redo the stuff that you have mentioned.